# Trying to open solution file but it can only read from a fixed file path

Tags: c#

I have to submit my university assignment today which involves copying the directory of the solution and everything in it. We are advised to check that we can open it from our saved directory as this will ensure that the marker will also be able to open it correctly. However, when I try to open it after saving it every class has an exclamation mark beside it and I get the error -

Error   3 Source file 'C:\Users\Desktop\backuo\stationaryNest.cs' could not be opened ('Unspecified error ')    AntSim

This is not the file path I am even opening it from! It seems there is a greyed out property for each class called 'full path', and that path is in it and is unchangeable. How do I make it so the file path is wherever you open it from ?

Comment: Are these files (classes) in a project?

Comment: yes they are and all of them get this error

Comment: `stationaryNest.cs` file may not exists in the specified directory. In this case you have to exclude it before compiling.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio and how did you add the files to the project? Also, right mouse click on the project and choose "unload project" (you can reload it), then choose to edit the project. Now scroll down the XML to one of these files and post here the few line, ought to be a "hint" xml element.

Comment: it says that every single class may not exist not just the stationarynest.cs

Comment: <Compile Include="..\..\..\..\..\..\Desktop\backuo\AntObject.cs">
      <Link>AntObject.cs</Link>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Program.cs" />
    <Compile Include="..\..\..\..\..\..\Desktop\backuo\Game1.cs">
      <Link>Game1.cs</Link>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="..\..\..\..\..\..\Desktop\backuo\stationaryFood.cs">
      <Link>stationaryFood.cs</Link>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="..\..\..\..\..\..\Desktop\backuo\stationaryNest.cs">
      <Link>stationaryNest.cs</Link>
    </Compile>

Comment: So do I need to change the addresses to just ..\..\ or something?

Comment: Ok. The paths here are relative to the project when you added them to the project. It looks like your source files were on your desktop and the project somewhere else. See ".\..\..\..\..\..\".

Comment: Reload your project (right mouse click on it), then view project's properties to check its folder. You could edit the csproj file.

Comment: yeah that makes sense! So how to fix it so anyone can open it if I send it to them?

Comment: what should I change the directories to? instead of ="..\..\..\..\..\..\Desktop\backuo\stationaryFood.cs

Comment: Now I know what has happened I posted an answer to you. Yes you can edit the XML but easier to move the files and do as per my answer ... good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to place your source files in the same folder, or a child folder, that the csproj file sits in. This then means you can copy the folder and maintain the relative relationship between project and its files.

Same goes for the solution. Make sure the csproj file is in the same folder, or a child folder of the sln file. You want to copy the folder the sln folder is in. Everything else needs to be child.

To fix:
- Remove all files from the project (in VS)
- Select the project and press the show all button on the solution explorer's tool bar.
- Now you will see your files grayed out (if in child folder), right mouse click and select "add to project".